# Locally style text in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

Let's say I would like `matplotlib` to display the following styled text in a plot:

> **This should be bold**, *this should be italics* and this should be a normal style.

**How should I do?** The following works...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

plt.text(0, 0, r"\textbf{This should be bold}, \textit{this should be italics} ad this should be a normal style.")
plt.show()
```

but, apart from being overkill, is quite slow... I also know that I can make successive calls to `plt.text` and pass it arguments like `fontweight = "bold"`, but this is even worse, since I would have to compute exactly at what place I should put all the boxes...

My question is actually part of a bigger problem: I would like to have, side by side, a plot and a text describing the plot. The text may contain tables and may need to be styled. For the moment, I create a `figure`, add two `axes` objects (one for the plot, one for the text) side by side but I am starting to fear that this approach will not allow me to style the text the way I want. **Is there a nicer way?**

Answer (score 1):

According to matplotlib documentationat https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text, the two ways you can style the text is either by using the inbuilt attributes like `fontweight` you mentioned, or by using LaTeX (which is what you do in your code).

LaTeX is more powerful, so I would suggest you go with it, especially if you need tables and stuff.